# Resource plant anatomy/lifecycle vocabulary

Tags: botany, book-recommendation

I've been curious about a lot of vocabulary words in the world of botany. I've had quite a bit  of trouble finding somewhere online to help me out, but I'm having some trouble finding a resource like that.

Optimally, I'm looking for something with diagrams of anatomy, over the course of time, maybe some photo examples, and some sort of dictionary to accompany. Is there anything like this, online or offline that anyone knows about?

Comment: Re-reading your question, I realize my answers below may be too general. Are you looking for a resource specifically about ontogeny, for example seed>seedling>adult anatomy?

Comment: I mostly wanted to know what parts of the plant are being affected by different things. For example, I have some apple seedlings that had a problem up to the ridge where the cotyledon stopped and the rest of the plant started, is there a name for that, if so, what is it?

Comment: I imagine there are resources targeted specifically to growers, and that the folks in the Gardening SE would be better positioned to tell you about them. However, I've also added one more resource to my answer below that may help.

Comment: I find that the folks at Gardening SE are incredibly knowledgeable, but aren't exactly botanists... I like both sides and was curious what to ask perhaps a botany professor. Thank you for your answer! I think that book looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**specifically development-focused**

*An Introduction to Plant Structure and Development* by Beck looks comprehensive and has been well-reviewed. It has both photos and diagrams, and sections certainly deal specifically with growth/lifecycle. It's [available to preview or purchase as an ebook on Google Play](http://books.google.com/books?id=zSK1BuxMh9cC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).

**more general plant anatomy vocabulary resources**

In print, [Plant Identification Terminology: an illustrated glossary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0964022168) by Harris and Harris is a fairly standard reference, and I've found it very useful both for looking up terms and for just flipping through.

Online, but with fewer diagrams, you could try the Glossary page on the [Angiosperm Phylogeny Website](http://www.mobot.org/MOBOT/research/APweb/).

This might sound silly, but if you're looking for more of a course on the fundamentals rather than a dictionary of the specifics, the [Botany Coloring Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0064603024) is actually a great, seriously useful work.